# Breaking While Loop for multiple inputs of list...for nested list

Tags: python, list, loops, input, while-loop

Hi I'm trying to get multiple inputs in the form of a list, which is nested inside a list. I'm able to get the output but not able to break out from the loop.

```
values = []
while True:
    val = list(input("Enter an integer, the value ends if it is 'stop': "))
    if val == 0:
        exit()
    values.append(val)
    print(values)
```

I even used break..after the if condition..no Joy !!

```
Enter an integer, the value ends if it is 'stop': 4569
[['4', '5', '6', '9']]
Enter an integer, the value ends if it is 'stop': 666655
[['4', '5', '6', '9'], ['6', '6', '6', '6', '5', '5']]
Enter an integer, the value ends if it is 'stop': 5222
[['4', '5', '6', '9'], ['6', '6', '6', '6', '5', '5'], ['5', '2', '2', '2']]
Enter an integer, the value ends if it is 'stop': 0
[['4', '5', '6', '9'], ['6', '6', '6', '6', '5', '5'], ['5', '2', '2', '2'], ['0']]
```

This is the type of output i'm looking for but whenever I press 0...it does not break the loop..

also using if val == list(0)  and if list(val) == list(0) and many other permutations either gives me an error or does not break out from the While Loop...Please Help..Thank you

Comment: In your example output you do not input `'stop'` anywhere. Is this a mistake? It seems from the input message that `'stop'` should end the current sub-list and start the next. Please clarify what inputting 'stop' and 0 should do.

Comment: Actually I got the solution...wasn't able to delete it...my mistake was if val == (['0'])

Comment: well i intended to use 'stop' or '0'...regardless it had to be a str value inside a list

Answer (score 1):

The returned value of [`input`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#input) is an instance of `str`. So in any case you would need to use the condition `val == '0'` in your if-statement. But since you are creating a list from the returned value of `input` you would need to change your code to the following:

```py
values = []
while True:
    val = list(input("Enter an integer, the value ends if it is 'stop': "))
    if val == ['0']:
        exit()
    values.append(val)
    print(values)
```